# Variable letter spacing?

Tags: letterspacing

I am using this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{LetterSpace=5}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}    
\hyphenchar\font=-1 % disabling hyphenation except bold and italic words

\begin{document}
\sloppy % interword spacing to avoid margin misalignment    
\lipsum[1-30]    
\end{document}
```

I tried asking at the end of another question, but I was said it couldnt be done. The idea is about reproducing something I have seen being done in InDesign. Here `\sloppy` adds white space between words to keep the justify without hyphenation. In order to give the idea of a continuous flow, adobe also adds spacing between characters and minimizes those white spaces. Is it possible to do something similar in LaTeX ?

This is an example of what I mean in InDesign for the same text

[image]

(it looks quite acceptable I think)

Comment: look at the microtype package (which uses variable width characters rather than varying the inter character space)

Comment: Also, you can entirely disable hyphenation.

Comment: After checking the result in InDesign I decided it wasnt worth it. Both variable letter spacing and variable glyph size were quite noticeable, even at 3%, so if one disables hyphenation, /sloppy will have to be enough.